# How to create a pattern Validator that accepts ONLY string?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

Here is my code/

````
```**`*enter code here`<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName1" [(ngModel)]="firstName" #firstName1="ngModel" required pattern="^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$" >***```
````

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Input always returns its value as `string`, even if it's type is `number` returned value will still be a string.

Do you mean you want to prevent users from introducing numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+$/
```

to match an input string of alphabets only.

- [A-Za-z] will check all the alphabets (both lowercase and
  uppercase).
- ^ and $ will check that only these alphabets will be
  matched.

You can visit this link for more

http://www.regexlib.com/%28A%28wkA47Pz62Cv5hOWaV7Ce6NyB7V-Ftea9NhdYY4azOE8fR3qTvr5_UxMQ6CAIumda7hQ7LIjCqZj9xUkRM5ziSWzdKjVsWv4XnNWXIiurYCOXSdU6QsouN-EpXzlSHyJlKmIxGJh_8EBBN47yZqJhR2CgJnYLdOoQLJyshU0q1eejjF94ELUbgxu2rz_F0qRu0%29%29/CheatSheet.aspx